# Printing balance, What m i doing wrong?

Tags: java, account, bank

I want to maintain 100 Balance at all cost.
Please tell me what m i doing wrong?

```
    static void withdraw(float cash){

    if (balance>100)

    balance=balance-cash;
    System.out.println(balance);

    else 
        (balance<=100){
        System.out.println("You do not have enough balance");

    }
}
```

Comment: ehm, what tells you there is something wrong? I'm at a loss here.
Anyway: balance = balance - cash => if balance = 105 and cash is 50, what is the logical error that 'll occur then?

Comment: 1st calculate balance-cash and check whether balance-cash>=100 or not.

Comment: there are tons of syntactical mistakes in this code. `else (balance <= 100)` guess you forgot the if. `if(balance>100)` the next two statements belong to the condition, so surround them with brackets. And a logical mistake, you'll have to predict the balance after substracting cash, so `if(balance - cash > 100)...`

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do, but you should *definitely* use braces around your `if` body, and it's not clear what `(balance <=100)` is there for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put like this

```
    int cash = 10;
    int balance = 100;
    if (balance-cash>100){  
        balance=balance-cash;
        System.out.println(balance);
    }else
        System.out.println("You do not have enough balance");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably should be something more like:

```
if ((balance - cash) < 100) {
    System.out.println("You do not have enough balance");
} else {
    balance -= cash;
    System.out.println(balance);
}
```

Most tutorials are going to build up more complex idea from simpler ones, so taking the time to move through these steps is important.  In production code you'd want to return the balance from this function, and would want to remove any redundant code.  In the code above, we have redundant code when we determine whether the withdrawal brings the balance total below 100, and when we actually reduce the balance by the withdrawal amount in the else statement.

If you'll notice we actually perform the same mathematical operation twice once here: `((balance - cash) < 100)`

and again here: `balance -= cash;`

To remove this, we can do the calculation once and store it in a variable.  This is necessary because we don't know yet whether the balance will fall below 100 after this operation.  Without storing it in a variable we either need to repeat the operation as we already do, or add back in the withdrawal amount after if the balance becomes too low, which is an additional operation we don't need to do. That would look like this:

```
balance -= cash;
if (balance < 100) {
    System.out.println("You do not have enough balance");
    balance += cash;
} else {
    System.out.println(balance);
}
```

But this still requires one extra step - addition in the case our if statement fails.  Instead, what we can do is assign the result of our initial subtraction to a temporary variable, and if the if condition fails we can simply throw that away without any additional operations.  Like this:

```
float tempbalance = balance - cash;
if (tempbalance < 100) {
    System.out.println("You do not have enough balance");
} else {
    balance = tempbalance;
    System.out.println(balance);
}
```

This way we're not repeating ourselves or doing additional operations that we could eliminate.  This first principle you'll hear repeated as DRY - do not repeat yourself.  This just means any time you reuse the same code, operation, steps or procedure (here, subtraction) more than once, you should reconsider your code design and try and find a way to make that code reusable (a very good use for functions).

Ultimately I think your tutorial is going to have you return the balance rather than print it.  If it doesn't in your current lesson, at some point the course you're working through will introduce this idea as it makes much cleaner code in this case.  For example, refactoring this code we could write a function that looks like:

```
static float withdraw(float cash) {
    float tempbalance = balance - cash;
    if (tempbalance < 100) {
        return balance;
    } else {
        return tempbalance;
    }
}
```

We would likely create an additional function that looks like this:

```
static void makeWithdraw(float cash) {
    if (balance == (balance = makeWithdraw(cash))) {
        System.out.println("You do not have enough balance");
    } else {
        System.out.println(balance);
    }
}
```

With this design we can call makeWithdraw() any time we want to output to the user whether they have enough money to make their withdraw, or their balance after the withdraw.  We're also free to reuse our withdraw() function anywhere else in our code that we need to make withdraws, but don't want to print these messages.  This also solves the problem of repeating code, and is a safe way to blindly perform operations on the balance without worry that it will be modified in a way we don't expect.

Hopefully this is clearer.  Note that in the makeWithdraw() function it's necessary that we both have the comparison made in this order `(balance == (balance = withdraw(cash)))`, as well as having the assignment statement `(balance = withdraw(cash))` within separate parenthesis.  If you reverse the order you'll find we're always told we don't have enough balance because we modify the value of balance before we make the comparison, resulting in a true evaluation each time.  And if we don't properly encapsulate the assignment statement, Java will not be able to properly interpret what we mean.

Hopefully that helps and makes your lesson easier.  Here's the code all together in a class that separates these functions by themselves so you can see it as a whole:

```
public class BalanceTutorial {

    static float balance = 300;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        makeWithdraw(100);
        makeWithdraw(100);
        makeWithdraw(1);
    }

    static float withdraw(float cash) {
        float tempbalance = balance - cash;
        if (tempbalance < 100) {
            return balance;
        } else {
            return tempbalance;
        }
    }

    static void makeWithdraw(float cash) {
        if (balance == (balance = withdraw(cash))) {
            System.out.println("You do not have enough balance");
        } else {
            System.out.println(balance);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: the tutorial where i am learning from has used a new variable(tempbalance) what is use of this variable if we can already get result this way.

void withdraw(float cash){

double tempbalance= balance;
tempbalance-=cash;
if (tempbalance>=100){
balance-=cash
}
else{
System.out.println("Insufficient Balance");
}

Comment: I updated my answer to address this question.  Hope this helps.